# Splitting input code into 3 letters and using if statements to return DNA->Amino Acid Letter

Tags: python

It is reading the first 3 letters as expected but how do i get it to read the next 3 letters as a different string so that it can run through the if, elif, else statements again.

The else X is there because its not required that I do the rest of them.

The table is there only because its useful to see if its returning the correct  letter.

```
dna = input("Enter the DNA sequence to translate: ")

if dna == "ATA" or dna == "ATC" or dna == "ATT":
  print ("I")
elif dna == "CTA" or dna == "CTC" or dna == "CTG" or dna == "CTT" or dna == "TAA" or dna =="TTG":
  print ("L")
elif dna == "GTA" or dna == "GTC" or dna == "GTG" or dna == "GTT":
  print ("V")
elif dna == "TTC" or dna == "TTT":
  print ("F")
elif dna == "ATG":
  print ("M")
else:
  print ("X")


CodonDict = {
'ATT':'I',   'ATC':'I',  'ATA':'I',  'CTT':'L',  'CTC':'L',  
'CTA':'L',  'CTG':'L',  'TTA':'L',  'TTG':'L',  'GTT':'V',  'GTC':'V',  
'GTA':'V',  'GTG':'V',  'TTT':'F',  'TTC':'F',  'ATG':'M',  'TGT':'C',  
'TGC':'C',  'GCT':'A',  'GCC':'A',  'GCA':'A',  'GCG':'A',  'GGT':'G',  
'GGC':'G',  'GGA':'G',  'GGG':'G',  'CCT':'P',  'CCC':'P',  'CCA':'P',  
'CCG':'P',  'ACT':'T',  'ACC':'T',  'ACA':'T',  'ACG':'T',  'TCT':'S',  
'TCC':'S',  'TCA':'S',  'TCG':'S',  'AGT':'S',  'AGC':'S',  'TAT':'Y',  
'TAC':'Y',  'TGG':'W',  'CAA':'Q',  'CAG':'Q',  'AAT':'N',  'AAC':'N',  
'CAT':'H',  'CAC':'H',  'GAA':'E',  'GAG':'E',  'GAT':'D',  'GAC':'D',  
'AAA':'K',  'AAG':'K',  'CGT':'R',  'CGC':'R',  'CGA':'R',  'CGG':'R',  
'AGA':'R',  'AGG':'R',  'TAA':'X',  'TAG':'X',  'TGA':'X'} 

For example I input: ATT
Returns I as expected.

I input: ATTATT
Returns X as expected but how do I treat the 3 letters as separate.
It should return II.
```

Comment: Hi @luk, please mark an answer as accepted, if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example:

```
input = 'ATTATTTTAGGG'
for i in range(0,len(intput),3):
    print (input[i:i+3])
```

output:

```
ATT
ATT
TTA
GGG
```

> **Accessing Values in Strings** Python does not support a character type; these are treated as strings of length one, thus also considered
>   a substring.
>
> To access substrings, use the square brackets for slicing along with
>   the index or indices to obtain your substring. For example −
>
> ```
> var1 = 'Hello World!'  
> var2 = "Python Programming"
>
> print ("var1[0]: ", var1[0])  
> print ("var2[1:5]: ", var2[1:5])
> ```
>
> output:
>
> ```
> var1[0]:  H  
> var2[1:5]:  ytho
> ```

**solution1:**

```
dna_ = input("Enter the DNA sequence to translate: ")
for i in range(0,len(dna_),3):
    #print (dna_[i:i+3])
    dna = dna_[i:i+3]
    if dna == "ATA" or dna == "ATC" or dna == "ATT":
      print ("I")
    elif dna == "CTA" or dna == "CTC" or dna == "CTG" or dna == "CTT" or dna == "TAA" or dna =="TTG":
      print ("L")
    elif dna == "GTA" or dna == "GTC" or dna == "GTG" or dna == "GTT":
      print ("V")
    elif dna == "TTC" or dna == "TTT":
      print ("F")
    elif dna == "ATG":
      print ("M")
    else:
      print ("X")
```

**solution2:** (if u want to use dictionary that you have)

```
dna_ = input("Enter the DNA sequence to translate: ")
for i in range(0,len(dna_),3):
    #print (dna_[i:i+3])
    dna = dna_[i:i+3]
    for key, val in CodonDict.items():
        if key == dna:
            print (val)
```

output:

```
Enter the DNA sequence to translate: TGCCTG
C
L
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the string -

```
for i in range(int(len(dna)/3)):
    tmp = dna[i*3: (i+1)*3]
    if tmp == "ATA" or tmp == "ATC" or tmp == "ATT":
        print ("I")
    elif tmp == "CTA" or tmp == "CTC" or tmp == "CTG" or tmp == "CTT" or tmp == "TAA" or tmp =="TTG":
        print ("L")
    elif tmp == "GTA" or tmp == "GTC" or tmp == "GTG" or tmp == "GTT":
        print ("V")
    elif tmp == "TTC" or tmp == "TTT":
        print ("F")
    elif tmp == "ATG":
        print ("M")
    else:
        print ("X")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a sliding window kind of thing with a for loop and the step parameter of [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range), where you iterate over the DNA sequence up to 3 characters at a time:

```
dna = input("Enter the DNA sequence to translate: ")

amino_str = ''
for i in range(0, len(dna), 3):
  dna_part = dna[i:i+3]
  if dna_part == "ATA" or dna_part == "ATC" or dna_part == "ATT":
    amino_str += "I"
  elif dna_part == "CTA" or dna_part == "CTC" or dna_part == "CTG" or dna_part == "CTT" or dna_part == "TAA" or dna_part == "TTG":
    amino_str += "L"
  elif dna_part == "GTA" or dna_part == "GTC" or dna_part == "GTG" or dna_part == "GTT":
    amino_str += "V"
  elif dna_part == "TTC" or dna_part == "TTT":
    amino_str += "F"
  elif dna_part == "ATG":
    amino_str += "M"
  else:
    amino_str += "X"
print(amino_str)
```

**Example Usage 1:**

```
Enter the DNA sequence to translate: ATAATA
II
```

You could simplify this above code by making use of `CodonDict`:

```
amino_str = ''
for i in range(0, len(dna), 3):
  dna_part = dna[i:i+3]
  if CodonDict[dna_part] != None:
    amino_str += CodonDict[dna_part]
  else:
    amino_str = "ERROR: PARSING DNA SEQUENCE"
    break
print(amino_str)
```

**Example Usage 2:**

```
Enter the DNA sequence to translate: AGAATACGC
RIR
```

Answer (score 1):

I will change your `CodonDict` to a more compact structure, a list of tuples, where the first element of the tuple is the list of DNA triplets, and the second element in the expected amino acid letter as follows.

```
codon_list = [ (["ATA","ATC" ,"ATT"],"I") ,
                (["CTA" , "CTC" , "CTG", "CTT", "TAA", "TTG"], "L"),
                (["GTA" , "GTC" , "GTG",  "GTT"] , "V"),
                (["TTC", "TTT"], "F"),
                (["ATG"], "M")
                ]
```

I assume if the DNA sequence length is not a multiple of 3, I am exiting the code, not sure if that is the required behaviour or not

```
import sys

result = ''
dna_str = input("Enter the DNA sequence to translate!")

#Get the number of Amino Acids length
dna_len = int(len(dna_str)/3)
idx = 0

#If the DNA sequence is not a multiple of 3, exit the code!
if len(dna_str)%3 != 0:
    print("DNA sequence is not a multiple of 3! Exiting")
    sys.exit()

codon_list = [ (["ATA","ATC" ,"ATT"],"I") ,
                (["CTA" , "CTC" , "CTG", "CTT", "TAA", "TTG"], "L"),
                (["GTA" , "GTC" , "GTG",  "GTT"] , "V"),
                (["TTC", "TTT"], "F"),
                (["ATG"], "M")
                ]

#Iterate through all DNA sequence triplets
while idx < len(dna_str):

    #Get the DNA triplet
    dna = dna_str[idx:idx+3]

    #Get the amino acid
    amino_acid = [t[1] for t in codon_list if dna in t[0]]

    #If amino acid is not present, default to X, else get amino acid
    if not amino_acid:
        amino_acid = 'X'
    else:
        amino_acid = amino_acid[0]

    #Append to final result
    result += amino_acid

    #Increment the index
    idx+=3

print(result)
```

The possible outputs are:

```
Enter the DNA sequence to translate!ATT
I

Enter the DNA sequence to translate!ATTATT
II

Enter the DNA sequence to translate!AX
DNA sequence is not a multiple of 3! Exiting
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the CodonDict, you should use it:

```
dna = input("Enter the DNA sequence to translate: ").strip().upper()
rslt= [ CodonDict.get(dna[i:i+3],"?") for i in range(0,len(dna),3) ]
print(rslt,"\n", "".join(rslt))
```

It yields the quetion mark if the pattern does not match.
Or you can declare a function:

```
def triplet(d3):

    if d3 in ("ATA","ATC", "ATT"):
        return "I"
    if d3 in ("CTA","CTC","CTG","CTT","TAA","TTG"):
        return "L"
    if d3 in ( "GTA","GTC","GTG","GTT"):
        return "V"
    if d3 in ("TTC","TTT"):
        return "F"
    if d3 == "ATG":
        return "M"

    return "X"

r=""
for i in range(0,len(dna),3):

    r+=triplet(dna[i:i+3])

print(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

For a long input string, consider using the grouper function from the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Example processing:

```
>>> input_ = 'ATTATTTAA'
>>> groups = grouper(input_, n=3)
>>> for g in groups:
...     print(''.join(g))
... 
ATT
ATT
TAA
```

You code might look like:

```
groups = grouper(dna, n=3)
results = []
for g in groups:
    code = ''.join(g)
    results.append(CodonDict[code])
print(''.join(results))
```

If it's possible that the input contains values that are not in `CodonDict` you should specify a string `fillvalue` argument to `grouper` (perhaps a lower-case letter) so that the `join` does not fail, and handle the result of looking up a missing key in `CodonDict`.